# Python Tornado won't load .Css file

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, tornado

I am currently new to Tornado and I am trying to render my HTML page using Tornado. The issue i am having is getting Tornado to allow the css file to be applied on my html page. When i run the html alone without a web server the css file is automatically incorporated and applied. Using Tornado, the html content is fine, but the css simply refuses to apply.

I've tried using the full path of both my files through the href and tornado, also I've tried placing them outside of the .py script running tornado but i get the same errors

## Python Tornado code

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

port = 8080

class basicRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello world!")

class staticRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("C:/Users/user/Desktop/html/Project 1/index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", basicRequestHandler),
        (r"/site", staticRequestHandler)
    ])

    app.listen(port)
    print(f"Listening on {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

---

This is the link inside my html code. I've tried full and relative paths(same folder) but none seem to make a difference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\html\Project 
1\styles.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
```

The error that appears on my chrome console is:

(1) Not allowed to load local resource:

> file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/html/Project%201/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\user\Desktop\html\Project 1\styles.css` is a file path on your system. This will not work because browsers and servers communicate through HTTP URLS.

To load the CSS file, you'll need to use its URL.

Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/styles.css">`. Please read the documentation of using [`StaticFileHandler`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler) to learn more about its usage.